# Return average of column by type in R

Tags: r, mean, col

I have a data frame like this:

```
    df<-data.frame(Type=c("Cat","Cat","Dog","Dog","Dog","Horse","Horse","Horse"), A=c(3,2,1,4,5,3,4,2),B=c(1,2,3,3,4,1,4,2),C=c(2,1,4,5,2,1,3,2), D=c(4,1,2,4,3,4,2,5))


       Type A B C D
    1   Cat 3 1 2 4
    2   Cat 2 2 1 1
    3   Dog 1 3 4 2
    4   Dog 4 3 5 4
    5   Dog 5 4 2 3
    6 Horse 3 1 1 4
    7 Horse 4 4 3 2
    8 Horse 2 2 2 5
```

I want to get the averages of column B by types so, for example, the average of type Cat is 1.5 and Dog is 3.33 and so forth. Is there any function that would return the averages for all of the different types at the same time? The outcome I would like would be something like this

```
    Cat Dog  Horse
    1.5 3.33 2.33
```

I just know how to take the average of the column with

```
    mean(df$B)
```

but I don't know how to take into account the types.

Comment: @RonakShah Hi! I just want the averages by the column B.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Comment: `tapply(df$B, df$Type, mean)`

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate(df$B, by=list(Type=df$Type), FUN=mean)
```